# If argv[] is an array of pointer, how could printf("%s", argv[]) work?

Tags: c, pointers, argv

In the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  int index;
  for(index = 0; index < argc; index++) {
    printf("The %d is %s\n",index,argv[index]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

from the declaration `char *argv[]`,[cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) says it means 
`declare argv as array of pointer to char`, so I think the code should write like this :
`printf("The %d is %s\n",index,*argv[index]);`

as the following code:

```
void give_me_ptr(int *ptr){
  printf("the value of ptr is %p\n", ptr);
  printf("the value of ptr is %d\n", *ptr);
}

int main(void){
  int a = 10,index;
  give_me_ptr(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

it turns out

```
the value of ptr is 0x7fff76010b48
the value of ptr is 10
```

to me it means I should add * before pointer variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `printf` function, format specifier `%s` requires a *pointer* to the first character of the string as the corresponding argument. This is why you pass `argv[index]` to it. `argv[index]` is a pointer.

If you passed `*argv[index]`, you would be passing only the first character of the `argv[index]` string, which is incorrect. `%s` requires a pointer to the first character, not the character itself.

Comment: Wow! this is so difference from the scripting language, now I know the printf("%s") takes pointer. but I still can't understand why *argv[index] return only first character

Answer (score 4):

A c-style string specifier `%s` expects a character pointer to he first character of a string. On calling something like `printf()`, it prints characters from the pointer to the nearest null character.

`%d` on the other hand expects an actual integer and not a pointer to one. When you point a string to `argv[index]`, that translates to `*argv+index`, which is the pointer to the first character at the **location number**:index.

Comment: +1 for saying  it prints characters fro the pointer to the nearest null character

Answer (score 1):

Two things to clarify:

1) Consider this representation of argv:

```
char *argv[] = { "./progname", "arg1", "arg2", NULL };
```

as it is given in standards-conformant implementations. Now each element of argv is a string (char pointer) in itself, no furhter need to dereference them -- in that case you're getting the first character of the string only.

2) Even if you expect integer parameters to be given to your program, don't use the %d printf specifier -- arguments are ***always passed as strings***!

Answer (score 1):

This is how `printf` behaves: It consumes a pointer with `%p` or a pointer to char with `%s`, but an integer with `%d`.

[As a side note: technically, `argv` is of type `char **`, even if you declare it as `char * argv[]`. However, they are synonymous.]

Comment: +1 for letting me know `char **`